# Apache add wildcard subdomain on windows 7

Tags: subdomain

I am running on a windows 7 machine with apache installation not xampp trying to add a wildcard subdomain entry in my apache virtual hosts file but it doesn't seems to work

I've added example.local and it serves content from c:/Apache24/htdocs/examplemain without any problem but wildcard entry for subdomain for example.local  doesn't seems to work.

My http-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.local
    DocumentRoot c:/Apache24/htdocs/examplemain
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory c:/Apache24/htdocs/examplemain>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias  *.example.local
    VirtualDocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/examplemain/examplesubdomain"
</VirtualHost>
```

My Hosts file in windows 7

```
127.0.0.1       example.local
127.0.0.1       *.example.local
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use wildcard characters in the hosts file, neither on Windows nor in Linux.

Since the hosts file is completely under your own control you can trivially create any hostname you need, alternatively run your own DNS server.

Comment: Hmm thanks for reply i think windows hosts file is not smart enough to do this running my own dns server will allow me to add wildcard subdomains ?